# London-directed boardings (Schengen flights)

Tags: schengen

As far as my knowledge is concerned, Schengen airports divide Schengen flights from non Schengen ones, by considering the former as domestic ones, and I also realise that not every EU country is in Schengen (e.g Ireland and the UK, Brexit aside) and nor is every Schengen country in the EU (e.g Switzerland), but what I noticed (from a photo in an Italian airport) is that flights directed to London are put with those heading other European cities within Schengen, but how is that possible? I mean, I know that London is in the EU (Brexit aside), but aren't London-directed flights supposed to be considered as International flights, since the UK doesn't adhere to Schengen?

Comment: I don't know that this question is possible to answer without more specifics (which airport?). But broadly, the passengers need to pass through Schengen exit controls if they're traveling to the UK. How the airport organises that is an operational decision. Exit controls could be at the gate for example, rather than dividing the terminal.

Comment: @MJeffryes yep I've had exit controls right by the gate before in the Schengen area

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the airport. Sometime there are passport controls later, e.g. just near the gate, and such control will be done only when there is a flight outside Schengen. You see this in a lot of small holiday airports (also in Greece, Spain, etc.).

Sometime it is more convenient such setup, e.g. if there are few international flights, so no need to have a huge separate part, and/or with small aircrafts (so more convenient to use the domestic terminal), e.g. for transfer to planes.

EU is now strict on requiring control by entering/exiting Schengen area (since two years), so I expect controls.

Comment: Schengen  has always been strict on entering and exit control of the zone. Maybe you did not notice it more than two years ago, but it was there.

Comment: @Willeke: it was on news for some weeks, few years ago, about airlines required to delay flights because huge queues (because extra exit control checks) on holidays airports (from holiday to british isles). And no. I live few km from a boundary, I nearly never had passport control, also before our country entered in Schengen (and Schengen were already in place since years).

Comment: In that case the Schengen country near you did not what they should have done.

Comment: @Willeke: Why? Do you remember that before Schengen we could travel in most western Europe without having a passport control? Schengen was done to add freedom, it would never been accepted in many country otherwise. I would wonder on German enclave in Switzerland, on Italy enclave in Switzerland. Wikipedia list 3 (micro-)states with open border with "Schengen" but outside Schengen. Norway implemented checks to/from Svalbard only in 2011. What about Dutch territories? Then NL implemented border check? I doubt it did from beginning of Schengen. As you see rules are getting stricter.

Comment: Before Schengen every country did or did not check as they wanted. But the Schengen rules require strict outside borders and no checks on the inside borders, that is the difference

Comment: @Willeke: so let's disagree on that, and let's move on. I'm somewhat unnerved that it seems you know the rules much better then the country states which signed Schengen agreements.

Comment: @GiacomoCatanazzi The German enclave in Switzerland was within the Swiss Customs area since 1947 and had no border controls since 1967. [Büsingen am Hochrhein – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCsingen_am_Hochrhein)